# Unbinding a service from an activity other its originator

Tags: android, android-service

How can I go about unbinding a service after I've moved to a different activity? The main problem is that I no longer have a reference to the original `ServiceConnection` in the new activity, so I can't simply call `unbindService`. Is there a way to pass the `ServiceConnection` into the new activity, or can I grab a reference to the service some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you do something like this:

1- Start your service by calling `startService()`.

2- `bind()` your activity to your service in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`

3- Interact with it

4- `unbind()` your activity from your service in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`

Repeat #2 #3 #4 with other activities

5- Once you are done with your service, stop it by calling `stopService()`

Comment: Won't unbinding the service in between activities kill it? I haven't been using `startService` and `stopService` thus far.

Comment: If your service is running because you called `bindService`, then it will run only as long as another application component is bound to it.
That's why I've suggested to start it. Then you will be able to interact with it more easily. Don't forget to stop it when you are done since a started service can run in the background indefinitely.